# Migration is not able to find legacy database tables for some migrations

Tags: 7, migrations

The hosting server I am using is Pantheon.
I'm trying to migrate taxonomy over from D6 to D7 with a custom migration class.  The problem is that I'm getting different behaviors on my local repo and the one  on the server.  On the server, I get an error saying that

> Migration failed with source plugin exception: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base
>   table or view not found: 1146 Table
>   'legacy_database_name.migrate_map_tdmchanneltermparent' doesn't exist, in
>   /srv/bindings/3b34ee5b39e94f12ad1de632af512a5b/code/includes/database/database.inc:2171

I'm not sure why it is trying to connect to the legacy database for the map in this migration.

Here is my migration class:

```
class chalkTermParentMigration extends tdmTermMigration {
  public function __construct($arguments) {
    parent::__construct($arguments);
    $this->arguments = $arguments;

    $this->description = t('Chalk Term Parent Migration');

    $query = Database::getConnection('mig_dest', 'legacy')
      ->select('vocabulary', 'v');
    $or = db_or()->condition('v.vid', 10)
      ->condition('v.vid', 11, '=')
      ->condition('v.vid', 12, '=')
      ->condition('v.vid', 20, '=')
      ->condition('v.vid', 21, '=')
      ->condition('v.vid', 25, '=');
    $query->condition($or);
    $query->fields('v', array('vid', 'name'));

    $this->source = new MigrateSourceSQL($query);

    $this->destination = new MigrateDestinationTerm('chalk');

    $this->addFieldMapping('name', 'name');
    $this->addFieldMapping('field_legacy_id', 'vid');

    $source_key = array(
      'vid' => array(
        'type' => 'varchar',
        'length' => 255,
        'not null' => TRUE,
        'description' => 'Legacy Vocab ID',
      )
    );
    $this->map = new MigrateSQLMap($this->machineName, $source_key, MigrateDestinationTerm::getKeySchema());

  }

}
```

Here is how I have my legacy database connection information set up:

```
if (!defined(PANTHEON_ENVIRONMENT)) {
  $databases['mig_dest']['default'] = array(
    'database' => 'abc',
    'username' => 'abcdev',
    'password' => 'qwe123',
    'host' => 'localhost',
    'port' => '',
    'driver' => 'mysql',
    'prefix' => '',
  );
  $databases['default'] = $databases['mig_dest'];
} else {
  $databases['mig_dest']['default'] = array(
    'database' => $_ENV['DB_NAME'],
    'username' => $_ENV['DB_USER'],
    'password' => $_ENV['DB_PASSWORD'],
    'host' => $_ENV['DB_HOST'],
    'port' => $_ENV['DB_PORT'],
    'driver' => 'mysql',
    'prefix' => '',
  );
}

$databases['legacy']['default'] = array(
  'database' => 'legacy_db_name',
  'username' => 'uname',
  'password' => 'passwd',
  'host' => 'legacy_db_host',
  'port' => '',
  'driver' => 'mysql',
  'prefix' => '',
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`legacy_database_name.migrate_map_tdmchanneltermparent` is a table typically made by the Migrate module to perform a mapping between source DB data and destination DB data. There is typically `migrate_map` table(s) and for instance `migrate_messages` table(s).

Be sure to properly `Import` or `Rollback` migrations. If you clearing the database by hand and dropping any of these tables, Migrate can get confused. Sometimes I occassionaly MySQL `Truncate` these tables by hand during my job workflow, but then you need to be careful and understand what migrate is doing -- how it's mapping processed data or registering migrations.

**EDIT**:

Then as a work around I suggest following the documentation for [Map Tables](https://www.drupal.org/node/1014558) heading section and *explicity* define the connection you want the mapping table created on. Since you have what looks like a local test migration setup and a Pantheon setup add this `... = new MigrateSQLMap( ... );` in an `IF` statement to point to the correct Drupal destination connection name.

> When you construct the MigrateSQLMap object, add a fourth argument to
>   tell it explicitly the connection on which to create the mapping
>   tables.

Answer (score 2):

I had an error showing that:

> Migration failed with source plugin exception: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'DESTINATION_database_name.migrate_map_migrationname' doesn't exist, in /code/includes/database/database.inc:2171   even though I have checked the database and the table is there... Was hitting my head against the wall for a while .. :)

Adding `map_joinable` option solved the issue for me:

```
$this->source = new MigrateSourceSQL($query, $source_fields, NULL, array('map_joinable' => FALSE));
```

Exception was gone and migration was running normally.